# Couldn't load Hello-jni from loader

Tags: android, java-native-interface

i'm getting 'some trouble about the jni file that null on loading library

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load Hello-jni from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.test.myApplication-1.apk", zip file "/data/data/com.test.myApplication/code_cache/secondary-dexes/com.test.myApplication.apk.classes2.zip"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.test.Myapplication, /system/lib]]]: findLibrary returned null
                                                                     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:358)
                                                                     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:526)
                                                                     at com.test.myApplication.other.JNI.<clinit>(JNI.java:9)
                                                                     at com.test.myApplication.util.PrefUtils.write(PrefUtils.java:33)
                                                                     at com.test.myApplication.presentation.intro.SplashActivityV2.saveDeviceInfo(SplashActivityV2.java:121)
```

hope anyone can help. Thanks

Comment: Did you build the .so file?  It isn't in the apk

Comment: @GabeSechan i was move my project to another laptop, and i forget to copy the NDK folder that include the .so file to the new laptop. is it the problem?

Comment: Yes.  The so file is necessary, it has the compiled C/C++ code for the library.  Without it you can't call that code, so your app will crash.

Comment: @GabeSechan big thanks for your help gabe. :D